# Method sendVoice() Telegram bot - the file is empty

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

I have this JavaScript code:

```
bot.sendVoice(chatId, 'C:/Users/a.repetto/Desktop/repettobot/hello_world.ogg', {
     disable_notification: true,
     reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id
    }).then(function () {
    // reply sent!
    });
```

The file exists and contain the audio, but when I try to run the entire code I get this error:

> ""error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: File must be non-empty "

I have also tried with `sendAudio` but this also doesn't work.

Edit 1: To be more specific.

If I write a script with only 'sendAudio' or 'sendVoice', the file is sent correctly to Telegram. But if I use this blcok of script, the file results empty:

```
var Bot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

function sleep (time) {
return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

var speech_to_text = watson.speech_to_text({
username: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, //username from VCAPSERVICES
password: 'XXXXXXXX', //password from VCAP SERVICES
version: 'v1',
url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api'
});

var language_translation = watson.language_translator({
  username: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  password: 'XXXXXXXX',
  version: 'v2'
});

var text_to_speech = watson.text_to_speech({
  username: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  password: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
  version: 'v1'
});

var params = {
model: 'en-US_BroadbandModel', //you can change the language here
content_type: 'audio/ogg;codecs=opus',
continuous: true,
interim_results: false
};

var bot = new Bot('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', {polling: true }); //token generated by the bot you created
bot.on('message', function (msg) {
if(msg['voice']){ return onVoiceMessage(msg); }
});

function onVoiceMessage(msg) {
  var chatId = msg.chat.id;

  bot.getFileLink(msg.voice.file_id).then(function(link) {
    var recognizeStream = speech_to_text.createRecognizeStream(params);
    recognizeStream.setEncoding('utf8');
    recognizeStream.on('results', function(data) {
      var result = data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;
      var c = result;

      console.log("testo: " + result);

      bot.sendMessage(chatId, result, {
        disable_notification: true,
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id
      }).then(function(){})

      language_translation.translate({
        text: result,
        source: 'en',
        target: 'it'
      }, function(err,translation) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        else {
          var trad = translation.translations[0].translation;
          console.log("traduzione: " + trad + "\n")
        }
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, trad, {
        disable_notification: true,
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id
      }).then(function(){})
      var params1 = {
        text: trad,
        voice: 'it-IT_FrancescaVoice',
        accept: 'audio/ogg;codecs=opus'
      }
      bot.sendVoice(chatId, text_to_speech.synthesize(params1), {
        disable_notification: true,
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id
      }).then(function(promise){console.log(promise)})
    })
  })
  request(link).pipe(recognizeStream);
})
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using for Telegram API?

Comment: I use node-telegram-bot-api

Answer (score 0):

Telegram cannot send file from your PC. First upload your files and then replace local address with web address. Other way is send file to telegram bot and get `file_id` (use `getUpdate` method) and put `file_id` in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited the question in order to be more clear